# Dapper: How to return selected columns?

Tags: dapper

```
public List<Customer> getCustomer() 
{
    using (IDbConnection con=DapperConnection())
    {
        string sql = "Select * from Customer";
        return con.Query<Customer>(sql).Select(x => new { x.Id, x.LastName })
                    .ToList();
    }
}

class Customer 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set;}
}
```

Does anyone know how to return specific columns using dapper? What I am trying to achieve is to return just the `Id` and `LastName` as `List` so that I can bind them to my controls.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure exactly what you mean but surely you should return the customer object instead of an anonymous type, or at least make a smaller version of the customer object to be used by the controls

```
    public List<Customer> getCustomers()
    {
        using (IDbConnection con = DapperConnection())
        {
            string sql = "Select * from Customer";
            return con.Query<Customer>(sql).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Or if you dont like the overhead of returning the full customer object

```
    public List<CustomerBase> getCustomers()
    {
        using (IDbConnection con = DapperConnection())
        {
            string sql = "Select * from Customer";
            return con.Query<CustomerBase>(sql).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class CustomerBase
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer: CustomerBase
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        //Other props...
    }
```

Comment: If i return it as on object it will go just fine but lost the readability. I am using C# WinForms and sometimes i end up binding rows to comboboxes like i bind First and LastName to separate comboboxes. So, if i am going to subclass my customer, i think that is a paint to deal with.

Comment: In tha case I assume you are using first and last name as some kind of autocomplete in your controls? If so, I dont think you should deal with that in the data layer, rather from the data layer return full set of customer details and split it in the code behind of your winform instead. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, i ended up doing that way. Thanks sir